# Ruby - How to select some characters from string

Tags: ruby, string, function, char, substr

I am trying to find a function for select e.g. first 100 chars of the string. In PHP, there exists the **substr** [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Does Ruby have some similar function?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Try `foo[0...100]`, any range will do. Ranges can also go negative. It is [well explained in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html) of Ruby.

Comment: Also note that ```foo[0..100]``` and ```foo[0...100]``` are different. One is zero to one-hundred while the other is zero to ninety-nine.

Comment: Clarifying above: foo[0..100] is the _inclusive_ (0 to 100) and foo[0...100] is the _exclusive_ (0 to 99)

Comment: And to clarify @steenslag's suggestion, `foo[0,100]` is _exclusive_ as well.

Answer (score 53):

Using the `[]`-operator ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)):

```
foo[0, 100]  # Get 100 characters starting at position 0
foo[0..99]   # Get all characters in index range 0 to 99 (inclusive!)
foo[0...100] # Get all characters in index range 0 to 100 (exclusive!)
```

[Update for Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/): [Beginless ranges](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/08/19/ruby-2-7-adds-beginless-range.html) are here now (as of 2019-12-25) and are probably the canonical answer for "return the first xx of an array":

```
foo[...100]  # Get all chars from the beginning up until the 100th (exclusive)
```

Using `.slice` method ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-slice)):

```
foo.slice(0, 100)  # Get 100 characters starting at position 0
foo.slice(0...100) # Behaves the same as operator []
```

And for completeness:

```
foo[0]         # Returns the indexed character, the first in this case
foo[-100, 100] # Get 100 characters starting at position -100
               # Negative indices are counted from the end of the string/array
               # Caution: Negative indices are 1-based, the last element is -1
foo[-100..-1]  # Get the last 100 characters in order
foo[-1..-100]  # Get the last 100 characters in reverse order
foo[-100...foo.length] # No index for one beyond last character
```

[Update for Ruby 2.6](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/12/25/ruby-2-6-0-released/): [Endless ranges](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/rubys-new-infinite-range-syntax-0-97777cf06270) are here now (as of 2018-12-25)!

```
foo[0..]      # Get all chars starting at the first. Identical to foo[0..-1]
foo[-100..]   # Get the last 100 characters
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is helpful to see the different nuances with the [] operator, not just necessarily the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.first(100)` where `foo` is a String